# Pandas DataReader not recognizing string types arbitrarily

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, pandas-datareader

I am using Spyder 3.2.3 and Python 3.6

Sometimes when I run the following code, it works.

```
symbol='AMD'
start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()  
df = web.DataReader(symbol, 'robinhood', start, end)
```

But sometimes it gives the following error, without changing anything:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 4, in 
>      df = web.DataReader(symbol, 'robinhood', start, end)
>
> File "/Users/vinceskretch/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site->packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 391, in DataReader
>     session=session).read()
>
> File "/Users/vinceskretch/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site->packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 77, in read
>      return self._read_one_data(self.url, self.params)
>
> File "/Users/vinceskretch/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site->packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 86, in _read_one_data
>      out = self._get_response(url, params=params).json()
>
> File "/Users/vinceskretch/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site->packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 136, in _get_response
>      last_response_text = response.text.encode(response.encoding)
>
> TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be str, not None

The code used to work fine for 6 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Robinhood has shut down this endpoint. If that is the case, the Robinhood data connection will likely be deprecated in `pandas-datareader`. For now, other data sources such as [Quandl](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#quandl) or [Alpha Vantage](https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/stable/remote_data.html#alpha-vantage) can retrieve the data which you are requesting.